# Finding nearest timeindex for many categories

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to obtain the data points nearest to the query timestamp for multiple independent categories like this ([example in more detail in the gist](https://gist.github.com/talesa/babe9955b891c8f75611eaf8e4f48974)):

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(dt)
df_output = list()
for category in df.category.unique():
    df_temp = df[df.category == category]
    i = df_temp.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')
    latest = df_temp.iloc[i]
    df_output.append(latest)

pd.DataFrame(df_output)
```

The issue with this approach is that it is very slow (and obviously feels very blunt). Profiling suggests the bottleneck is `iloc`, which seems odd.

What is a faster/more correct way to go about it? Is there a way to obtain the result for all of the categories at once? (I'm thinking of some `groupby` magic)

Is `pandas` capable of doing it or should I switch to some other timeseries storage method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas was made for time-series data so this is it's bread and butter.  Try this for performance:

```
dt = '2017-12-23 01:49:13'
df["timedelta"] = abs(df.index - pd.Timestamp(dt))
df.loc[df.groupby(by="category")["timedelta"].idxmin()].drop("timedelta", axis=1)
```

This is creating a new column called timedelta, named after `pandas.Timedelta` class, and then using `groupby` to combine all the categories, find the smallest timedelta in each and return their index into `.loc`.  Lastly I dropped the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `groupby`, but you'll still need to use `iloc`. Here's a solution:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-23 01:50:30')

def find(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(dt, method='nearest')]).T

new_df = df.groupby('category').apply(find)
new_df


                                        category    value
category            
A           2017-12-23 01:50:21.687     A           1
B           2017-12-23 01:50:21.661     B           3
```

If you don't want the multi-index that indicates the category, you can just drop it like this:

```
new_df.index = new_df.index.droplevel()
new_df

                            category    value

2017-12-23 01:50:21.687     A           1
2017-12-23 01:50:21.661     B           3
```